# Someone offers someone an opportunity vs. Someone offers an opportunity to someone

Tags: sentence-construction

I am trying to express an idea but I am not sure it is proper:

I'm writing a letter to someone explaining a situation, but I need to be sure the person will understand.

My sentence is the following:

> *Mr.V, our yoga teacher, offers the opportunity to non-experienced
> teachers from Europe, to organize outdoor multiple yoga courses to
> celebrate summer.*

Is this correct? Does it sound natural? Or do I have to write way like this:

> *Mr V, our yoga teacher, offers to non-experienced teachers from Europe the opportunity to organize (...)*.

Or even,

> *Non-experienced teachers from Europe are given the opportunity by Mr
> V, our yoga teacher, to organize an outdoor multiple yoga course*

I have the feeling that English speakers won't understand... Can you?

Comment: Wording will depend on whether the letter is making an offer, or is simply describing an existing offer.

Answer (score 0):

This one is the best:
"Mr V, our yoga teacher, offers to non-experienced teachers from Europe the opportunity to organize (...)".

Except... what is an "outdoor multiple yoga course"? That wording is hard to understand. That is the unclear part.

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure where to post this, but I wanted to thank you for your answer!

Comment: PS: An outdoor multiple yoga course is, a yoga course *al fresco*, and multiple because there are many teachers (the recipient of this email will understand since they use that wording too). thank you again!

Comment: "Mr V., our yoga teacher, offers to non-experienced teachers from Europe the opportunity to organize multi-instructor outdoor yoga courses to celebrate summer."